# Loading a native library for Android using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm fairly new to Android development and I've been trying for a while now but I just don't get it. I'm writing an app for android that creates gifs, and for that I'm using [this library](http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/#gifflen). I compiled it into an .so but now I just don't understand how to actually load it. I put the .so in /libs/armeabi/ but when I load it like

```
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("gifflen");
    }
```

it throws

```
   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13565): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gifflen: findLibrary returned null
```

Am I supposed to put it somewhere else? Or is this because of some setting in Eclipse I was supposed to change?
I've mucked about with the native library option in Java Build Path but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. 
I've also googled around a bit and found an answer that said to select select Android Tools->Add Native Support but I don't have that option.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You built into into an .so how?  Using the NDK?  If so then the file that was created should have been called libgrifflen.so.  Was it?

Comment: THANK YOU. I renamed it to gifflen.so from libgifflen.so for some silly reason. I didn't think that it would matter.

Comment: "You built into into an .so how?"
Can you repeat it in english please.

Comment: "How did you build it into an .so?"  I was asking what tools he used in order to build the .so.

Answer (score 13):

Substantially, you need to tell the system that such library exists and where it is located. This is done inside Eclipse by right-clicking on the project name and then selecting "Android Tools" and then "Add Native Support". If the project already has Native Support, this option is not present - if you are a beginner it is better that you create a new project from scratch.

Comment: sorry, I've faced this problem, but I can't find Add "Native  Support" there.

Comment: Oh dear good God! This is really good sh*t! I must have read all existing posts on `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when I came across your answer and it was good.

Comment: No, this is not the answer.  Having "native support" selected in eclipse has nothing to do with an **already built** library being packaged or not.  It merely allows you to use eclipse (vs something else) to language-aware-edit and drive the ndk to *build* the library - but that is not the problem here.